# Higher Order Component - listening for onChange

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a HOC to help with forms in my React app (for practice).

```
// components/Wrapper.js
import React from 'react';

export default WrappedComponent => class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Submitting form...");
  }

  render() {
    return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} onSubmit={this.onSubmit} onChange={this.onChange}/>;
  }
};
```

and I export from the main index file using:

```
export Wrapper from './components/Wrapper';
```

Then I can do:

```
// LoginPage.js
import { Wrapper } from '../Somewhere'  

...
<form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
  <label>Email Address</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
...
```

and I wrap using:

```
export default Wrapper(LoginPage);
```

I'm trying to make it as easy to use as possible (as others may make use if it). Therefore, I want to be able to remove the `onChange` props in the `input` boxes and somehow build this functionality in so that `onChanges` are detected automatically by the HOC.

**How can I build a component that can be used for input boxes that will have `onChange` added automatically?**

Comment: What is this syntax? `export default WrappedComponent => class extends React.Component {..`   It doesn't look like your HOC has a name, and I can't see you using it in your example.

Comment: @jonahe I omitted this to make the question more concise but added some extra info now. Not sure it helps in any way though.

Comment: The way you're describing it I'm not sure it can be done in a nice way. The inputs would need to get the onChange callback one way or another. If you don't plan on passing them down when they are declared (`<input type="password" ...etc />`), you'd need to somehow get a reference to all the inputs at a later stage, maybe in your HOC (since that's the component that know how to deal with onChage). That sounds messy to me. But yeah, maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Do you have an example of an existing library you've used that has an API similar to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks. I guess redux-form does something similar. If you make a form and add `Field` components then the `onChange` is detected automatically. I've been digging around the source code for a while but not really sure which bit is addressing this issue.

Comment: Ok, yeah redux-form has a pretty "magical" API like that, that's true. Took a quick look at [some of the source code](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/createField.js) and it somehow seems to rely on the fact that both the parent (the connected base component) and the child (like `Field`) have access to the same context. Example: `if (!context._reduxForm) { throw new Error ..` .  So I think you must let the input components be custom as well.   But yeah, I will not pretend to understand it even remotely enough to replicate that feature.

Comment: Ha ha - it's a lot to get your head around. Wasn't sure whether to make use of context. The docs seem to suggest it's a work in progress and breaking changes are likely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap html element input in your react component, and set defaultProps: onChange: () => {}, and define other props like input type etc...

And then markdown this inputs as components:

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
  <CustomInput type="text" label="Login" .../>
</form>
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking! I know how to pass props from the wrapper because I've shown that in the question. I want to know how I can "bake in" the onChange functionality so that the wrapper detects when values in the text boxes change (without adding onChange to the input itself).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the input values would be:

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this._nameInput).value;
    const email = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this._emailInput).value;
    const password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this._passwordInput).value;


    // submit the data...
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          ref={nameInput => this._nameInput}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
        />
        <input
          ref={emailInput => this._emailInput}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        <input
          ref={passwordInput => this._passwordInput}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Hope that helps.